# MSVC++ and SSE2

Tags: visual-c++, sse, intrinsics

why does _**mm_slli_epi64(_mm128i x, int 1)** appear to stop working after five successive applications of shifting by one-bit each time and does not appear to shift bits in byte [9] to byte [8] at all when using msvc++ 2019 64-bit. I have chosen to show just bytes [08] thru bytes [15] until its necessary for further discussion.  I am using win 10 on iMac with Parallels for Windows.

output:
Example left shift of __m128i variable

Example 1:
original LE:  0x0706050403020100 0F0E0D0C0B0A0908 Little Endian
original BE: [08]-[09]-[0A]-[0B]-[0C]-[0D]-[0E]-[0F] Big Endian

Byte:        [08] [09] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15]

1. result BE 01: [10]-[12]-[14]-[16]-[18]-[1A]-[1C]-[1E]
2. result BE 02: [20]-[24]-[28]-[2C]-[30]-[34]-[38]-[3C]
3. result BE 03: [40]-[48]-[50]-[58]-[60]-[68]-[70]-[78]
4. result BE 04: [80]-[90]-[A0]-[B0]-[C0]-[D0]-[E0]-[F0]
5. result BE 05: [00]-[21]-[41]-[61]-[81]-[A1]-[C1]-[E1]
6. result BE 06: [00]-[42]-[82]-[C2]-[02]-[43]-[83]-[C3]
7. result BE 07: [00]-[84]-[04]-[85]-[05]-[86]-[06]-[87]

Comment: Yes, that's how epi64 works.  Perhaps you meant to use _mm_slli_si128.

Comment: It's a SIMD bit-shift on packed 64-bit elements.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psllw:pslld:psllq.  Note that `_mm_slli_si128` which Hasn mentioned is a byte-shift, not a bit-shift, but does shuffle bytes across the whole vector.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pslldq

Comment: I understand that bit 8 of element 8 does not shift to bit 1 of element [7], but shouldn't bit 8 of element[9] shift to bit 1 of element 8?

Comment: Everything that was labeled "Big Endian" actually isn't, it's Little Endian. Perhaps that's where the confusion came from? And bits from element [9] shouldn't go into element [8], it's the other way around, it's a *left* shift after all.